# Equally distribute duplicate Timestamps in column

Tags: python, pandas

Given this data frame with the date `2020-01-02` repeated three times

```
df_original
                 time
0 2020-01-02 00:00:00
1 2020-01-02 00:00:00
2 2020-01-02 00:00:00
3 2020-01-03 00:00:00
```

I would like to transform it into the following, where the three `2020-01-02` timestamps have been equally distributed between `2020-01-01` and `2020-01-02`.

```
df_expected
                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 12:00:00
2 2020-01-02 00:00:00
3 2020-01-03 00:00:00
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this for a data frame with a `time` column of length ~`10_000_000`?

First I would have to find the duplicated timestamps, which I suppose could be done using `df.duplicated()`. Then I would have to somehow go through all the duplicated blocks and do something like this:

`pd.date_range(timestamps[0] - Timedelta(days=1), timestamps[0], len(timestamps))`

But I'm not sure how to achieve this without looping.

## EDIT

Adding an extra data frame with the expected output

```
df_original
                  time
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00
1  2020-01-02 00:00:00
2  2020-01-02 00:00:00
3  2020-01-03 00:00:00
4  2020-01-03 00:00:00
5  2020-01-03 00:00:00
6  2020-01-04 00:00:00
7  2020-01-04 00:00:00
8  2020-01-04 00:00:00
9  2020-01-04 00:00:00
10 2020-01-05 00:00:00
```

```
df_expected
                  time
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00
1  2020-01-01 00:00:00
2  2020-01-02 00:00:00
3  2020-01-02 00:00:00
4  2020-01-02 12:00:00
5  2020-01-03 00:00:00
6  2020-01-03 00:00:00
7  2020-01-03 08:00:00
8  2020-01-03 16:00:00
9  2020-01-04 00:00:00
10 2020-01-05 00:00:00
```

An important note here is that in these examples I have used `Timedelta(days=1)` as the delta time to spread the duplicates over, but this delta could be any `Timedelta` value

Comment: Do you have only 3 same consecutive dates or can be more?

Comment: Can be more consecutive dates

Answer (score 2):

Try with `groupby` with `cumcount(ascending=False)`, and then multiply it by 12 hours:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'] - df.groupby('time').cumcount(ascending=False).mul(pd.Timedelta(hours=12))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 12:00:00
2 2020-01-02 00:00:00
3 2020-01-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: @U12-Forward - Tested and not.

Comment: @jezrael I mean it works for me, you can see the desired output is the same

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the correct result if you have two identical dates?

Answer (score 2):

Use custom function only for duplicted values of column `time` in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

m = df['time'].duplicated(keep=False)
f = lambda x: pd.date_range(x.iat[0] - pd.Timedelta(days=1), x.iat[0], len(x))
df.loc[m, 'time'] = df[m].groupby('time')['time'].transform(f)
print (df)

                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 12:00:00
2 2020-01-02 00:00:00
3 2020-01-03 00:00:00
```

For 4 values:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

m = df['time'].duplicated(keep=False)
f = lambda x: pd.date_range(x.iat[0] - pd.Timedelta(days=1), x.iat[0], len(x))
df.loc[m, 'time'] = df[m].groupby('time')['time'].transform(f)

print (df)
                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 08:00:00
2 2020-01-01 16:00:00
3 2020-01-02 00:00:00
4 2020-01-03 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value_counts` and `date_range`:

```
gen_dates = lambda x: pd.date_range(x['index'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1),
                                    x['index'],
                                    periods=x['time'])

df['time'] = df['time'].value_counts().reset_index() \
                       .apply(gen_dates, axis=1) \
                       .explode().reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
>>> df
                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 12:00:00
2 2020-01-02 00:00:00
3 2020-01-02 00:00:00
```

For 4 values:

```
>>> df
                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 08:00:00
2 2020-01-01 16:00:00
3 2020-01-02 00:00:00
4 2020-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the following dataframe:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [Timestamp('2020-01-01'), Timestamp('2020-01-02'), Timestamp('2020-01-02'), Timestamp('2020-01-02'), Timestamp('2020-01-03')]})`

Answer (score 0):

I've modified @U12-Forward's answer and made a function which handles all of my cases. @jezrael's answer is more direct and solves the issue, but unfortunately it is to slow for my ~20_000_000 row data frame.

```
def evenly_distribute_timestamps(df: DataFrame, 
                                 spread_timedelta: Timedelta = Timedelta(seconds=1), 
                                 ascending=True, time_column='time', inplace=False):
    if not inplace:
        df = df.copy()

    duplicates = df[time_column].duplicated(keep=False)

    spread_factors = spread_timedelta / (df.loc[duplicates, time_column].value_counts() - 1)

    df['cumcount'] = df.groupby(time_column).cumcount(ascending=ascending)
    cumcount = df[duplicates].set_index(time_column)['cumcount']
    df.drop('cumcount', inplace=True, axis=1)

    timedelta = (cumcount * spread_factors).reset_index(drop=True)

    if ascending:
        df.loc[duplicates, time_column] = df.loc[duplicates, time_column] + timedelta.values
    else:
        df.loc[duplicates, time_column] = df.loc[duplicates, time_column] - timedelta.values

    return df
```

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-04 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-04 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-04 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-04 00:00:00'),
                                Timestamp('2020-01-05 00:00:00')]})

>>> df
         time
0  2020-01-01
1  2020-01-02
2  2020-01-02
3  2020-01-03
4  2020-01-03
5  2020-01-03
6  2020-01-04
7  2020-01-04
8  2020-01-04
9  2020-01-04
10 2020-01-05

>>> evenly_distribute_timestamps(df, Timedelta(days=1), ascending=True)     
                  time
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00
1  2020-01-02 00:00:00
2  2020-01-03 00:00:00
3  2020-01-03 00:00:00
4  2020-01-03 12:00:00
5  2020-01-04 00:00:00
6  2020-01-04 00:00:00
7  2020-01-04 08:00:00
8  2020-01-04 16:00:00
9  2020-01-05 00:00:00
10 2020-01-05 00:00:00

>>> evenly_distribute_timestamps(df, Timedelta(days=1), ascending=False)
                  time
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00
1  2020-01-01 00:00:00
2  2020-01-02 00:00:00
3  2020-01-02 00:00:00
4  2020-01-02 12:00:00
5  2020-01-03 00:00:00
6  2020-01-03 00:00:00
7  2020-01-03 08:00:00
8  2020-01-03 16:00:00
9  2020-01-04 00:00:00
10 2020-01-05 00:00:00
```